# No corresponding inner declaration found for (Modelica inner/outer)

Tags: modeling, modelica, openmodelica

I have recently started using Modelica (OpenModelica) as a modeling tool and I am facing a problem regarding the use of inner/outer functionalities. I am trying to create an environment model containing values for ambient temperature and pressure, so that other models can use this values. I have tried to do so with inner and outer keywords but I keep receiving the following warning:

> No corresponding 'inner' declaration found for component .Real
>   component.T0 declared as 'outer '. The existing 'inner' components
>   are:   .Real ambient.T0; defined in scope: Test.Ambient.   Check if
>   you have not misspelled the 'outer' component name.   Please declare
>   an 'inner' component with the same name in the top scope.   Continuing
>   flattening by only considering the 'outer' component declaration.

Below these lines you can see a simplification of the code I am trying.

The three models below these lines are contained in a package named Test.

The model for ambient in which a temperature T0  is defined as inner:

```
within Test;

    model Ambient

        inner Real T0;

        equation
            T0 = 300;

end Ambient;
```

The model of a component that tries to call T0 via outer operator:

```
within Test;

model Component

    Real T;
    outer Real T0;
    parameter Real k = 2;

    equation
        T = k * time + T0;

end Component;
```

Both models ambient and component are dragged and dropped in the combined model:

```
within Test;

model System
  Test.Ambient ambient annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-30, 30}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Test.Component component annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {30, -10}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation

end System;
```

When running System I get the aforementioned warning. Also, there is one  variable more than equations (which makes sense since it is not being able to connect Component.T0 with Ambient T0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use-case seems pretty similar to what is done in `Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody` and  `Modelica.Fluid`. In both cases, there is a class that contains all the "global" properties of the system, called `world` or `system` respectively.

Therefore your class `Ambient` should defined to be an `inner` class. This is then accessed by an `outer` statement to re-use values from it. What would be possible when using your code, is to access `T0` from models **within** `Ambient`. Judging from your example code this is not what you want...

Applying the technique used in the MSL to your example, would result in the following code:

```
package Test
model Ambient
    inner Real T0;
  equation
    T0 = 300;
    annotation(defaultComponentPrefixes="inner");
end Ambient;

model Component
    Real T;
    Real T0 = ambient.T0;
    parameter Real k = 2;
  protected
    outer Test.Ambient ambient;
  equation
    T = k * time + T0;
end Component;

model System
  inner Test.Ambient ambient;
  Test.Component component;   
end System;

end Test;
```

Some comments:

- Accessing the variables with the outer statement is done in the `protected` part of the model, just to prevent to have the same variables multiple times in the result.
- The `defaultComponentPrefixes` annotation ensures, that the model has the prefix `inner` in case a graphical instance is created (as it is shown in the model `System`).

Comment: Thanks a lot Markus! I just tried your modified code and it worked perfectly. I realise now that I have to add the line "outer Test.Ambient ambient" so that i can later call to a property from ambient, and also to instantiate the model via inner keyword. Again, thanks a lot! It is very helpful.